# How do I correctly send a request in a loop?

Tags: php

After sending a response to me comes with a link to the next page with the products, how do I send requests to it while this link is in the response?

```
function get_data() {
  $array = [];
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $headers = array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json",
  );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  $res = json_decode($resp, true);

  while(isset($res['meta']['nextHref'])) {
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $res['meta']['nextHref']);
    $headers = array(
      "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
      "Authorization: Bearer $token",
      "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json",
    );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $resp = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    $res = json_decode($resp, true);
    $array[] = $res;
  }
  return $array;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need the while cycle there. Change your function so that it excepts an input parameter, and make it recursive by itself, like this:

```
function get_data($url) {
  $array = [];
  $curl = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  $headers = array(
    "accept: application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "Authorization: Bearer $token",
    "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json",
  );
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $resp = curl_exec($curl);
  curl_close($curl);
  $res = json_decode($resp, true);
  $array[] = $res;
  
  if (isset($res['meta']['nextHref'])) $array = array_merge($array, get_data($res['meta']['nextHref']));
  
  return $array;
}
```